# Root to leaf path with given sum in binary tree

Tags: c++, tree

For a given binary tree and a sum, I have written the following function to check whether there is a root to leaf path in that tree with the given sum.

```
/* 
//A binary tree node
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* left, * right;
}; 
*/

bool hasPathSum(Node *node, int sum)
{
    if(!node)
        return sum==0;

    return ( hasPathSum(node->left,  sum-node->data) || 
             hasPathSum(node->right, sum-node->data) );
}
```

Are there any edge cases in which the code will break? Also, do comment on the code style.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: The sum==0 statement is reached only when node==NULL. Otherwise hasPathSum is recursively called on left and right subtree until it reaches left or right subtree of a leaf node.

Comment: It seems fine to me.

Comment: Oops--I misread. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Give your operators some breathing space.

  ```
      if (!node) {
          return sum == 0;
      }

      return hasPathSum(node->left,  sum - node->data) || 
             hasPathSum(node->right, sum - node->data);
  ```

  Note that `return` expression needs no parenthesis.
- `sum - node->data` seems more natural to be expressed once:

  ```
      sum -= node->data;
      return hasPathSum(node->left,  sum) || 
             hasPathSum(node->right, sum);
  ```
- I see no edge cases except possible overflows.

Comment: Thanks, henceforth I will see to it that operators get space to breathe.
I see in your code you have omitted the parenthesis in `return` statement and added braces for `if` construct. Will you suggest me how do I decide whether to use/omit braces in the code(of course in cases where it is not necessary to use them), whether I should use/omit the parenthesis(again when they are not necessary to be used)?

Comment: @shridharfly It is generally recommended to _never_ omit braces. Parenthesis OTOH are less strict. Use them to emphasize the priority of subexpressions. Parenthesis around an entire expression are never used; particularly with `return` expression.